# R - Why isn't grep returning multiple indices?

Tags: r

For this code:

```
> grep("abc","abcabcabc", value=FALSE)
[1] 1
```

I thought it would give me all of the indices where "abc" appears in the string.  Am I doing something wrong?  Is there a different method I should use to find all occurrences of a pattern in a string?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `gregexpr()` instead:

```
gregexpr("abc","abcabcabc")
[[1]]
[1] 1 4 7
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 3 3 3
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

This tells you there are matches at positions 1, 4 and 7. Each match was 3 characters in length.

---

If you want to print the positions of the match only, without the additional attributes, make use of this trick:

```
x <- gregexpr("abc","abcabcabc")
lapply(x, c)
[[1]]
[1] 1 4 7
```

This makes use of the fact that `c()` strips the attributes from all its arguments. So, you use `lapply` to traverse the list, pass each element to `c()` and get back the same element without its attributes.

---

OK, I have just been Ripleyed by proxy.

Don't use `lapply(x, c)`.  Do this instead:

```
lapply(x, as.vector)
[[1]]
[1] 1 4 7
```

For reasons why, see `fortune(185)`

```
library(fortunes)
fortune(185)

I don't like to see the use of c() for its side effects. In this case Marc's
as.vector seems to me to be self-explanatory, and that is a virtue in programming
that is too often undervalued.
   -- Brian D. Ripley (on how to convert a matrix into a vector)
      R-help (March 2007)
```

Comment: Thanks.  So how do I print just the "1 4 7" part of the gregexpr output?

Comment: Someone has to mention `fortune(185)`, I suppose.

Comment: See also `stringr::str_locale_all`

Answer (score 4):

`grep` only returns the index value where a match is found.

```
x <- c('a', 'b', 'aa', 'abc', 'bc')

grep('a', x)
# [1] 1 3 4
```

You can use `value = TRUE` to have `grep` return the matches rather than indicies too.

Depending on your use case, you want to use `gsub` or `gregexpr`.  The help for all these functions is all contained on the same page, `?grep`.